# could not find the function ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

after estensive research, I decided to post my question.
I need to work on some graphics, so I decided to install ggplot2 package.

Well what I did was:

```
install.packages("ggplot2")
require(ggplot2)
```

But nothing happens, when I try to use ggplot it comes out something like "could not find the function "ggplot2"" as if the packages was never installed.

i suppose it is something to do with directories in which the package is downloaded, but seriously, have no idea.

I get the error using the code:

```
ggplot2(data=tweets, aes(tweets$created_at)) + 
geom_bar(aes(fill=..count..), alpha=0.5, size=0.5, binwidth=60*5) + 
scale_x_datetime("tweets$created_at") + 
scale_y_continuous("Number of tweets")
```

any way I paste what it shows after the "installation":

> install.packages("ggplot2")
>   --- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
>   provo con l'URL
>   'http://www.freestatistics.org/cran/bin/macosx/contrib/3.0/ggplot2_0.9.3.1.tgz'
>   Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2647855 bytes (2.5 Mb)
>   URL aperto

```
==================================================
```

> downloaded 2.5 Mb
>
> The downloaded binary packages are in
>       /var/folders/zr/t7y5pvy94n557yv7pv2hlx6r0000gn/T//Rtmp1mD2Vi/downloaded_packages

Help will be appreciated"""
cheeers
vvvv

Comment: what code are you using when you get that error?

Comment: ggplot2(data=tweets, aes(tweets$created_at)) + 
 geom_bar(aes(fill=..count..), alpha=0.5, size=0.5, binwidth=60*5) + 
 scale_x_datetime("tweets$created_at") + 
 scale_y_continuous("Number of tweets")

Comment: If its not too much trouble I'd say just reinstall R with the latest version and try again.

Answer (score 13):

I think everything has downloaded correctly, you are using the wrong function name. Use `ggplot` not `ggplot2` i.e.

```
ggplot(data=tweets, aes(x = created_at)) + 
    geom_bar(aes(fill=..count..), alpha=0.5, size=0.5, binwidth=60*5)
```

Also dont use `$` inside `aes` calls.

Comment: OK, it launches the quartz but the graph is black... but anyway, if I, let's say, would like to type simply ggplot2() after the installation, it would not give me "could not find the function ggplot2" anyway, or not?

Comment: yes it would give you `"could not find the function ggplot2"` when you enter `ggplot2()` but not for `ggplot()`. That would return `Error no layers in plot`

Comment: ok cool! thank you!!! but let's say. I want to plot graph in which on the x I have a rate per hour and on x I have time. In particular: I have a file of messages from twitter ordered by timestamp, and I would like to plot the message rate (i.d. the sum of the all messaged for each hour of the day) vs. time. Is there a way to make the sum automatically and obtain a plot with    ggplot?

Comment: @user3103007 , if you have another question please post it as a new question (with a reproducible example etc etc etc ... http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000 ) (and see `?stat_summary`)